# Are PayPal merchant accounts linked to a domain name such that changing our web address will cause payment problems?

Tags: domains, paypal

Is a PayPal merchant account linked to a domain name? I have a project where an established website is going to be changing their domain name. Will PayPal checkout continue to work on the website after the domain name is changed, or are there settings in PayPal that need to be updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not.  It's linked to a business or Personal name.  As long as you have the API key, you can run your checkout process fine from any domain name really.